# Installing pocketsphinx for android on windows

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to build an application on android using pocketsphinx. I've downloaded the package on sourceforge, but the instructions http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx#windows doesn't work. Is there additional software needed to compile the demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build an application on android using pocketsphinx you need to follow Android tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

There is no need to compile any additional packages, you just checkout the demo, import it into Android Studio and run.

You should not look on tutorialpocketsphinx at all, it's for desktop version.

You don't need Cygwin

To unzip tar.gz you can use Winrar or you can download zip archive here:
http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo

Information on https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo is seriously outdated. You should NOT use it.

Comment: So I don't need Cygwin etc as listed? The zipped file is .tar.gz, how would I unzip that? Or the process listed here https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo ?

Comment: I am encountering the same problem described here (http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/06d25a58/ )by Jayapraju. I am using Eclipse with ADT (version 23)

Comment: If you read tutorial carefully it says in plain English to **INSTALL ECLIPSE JAVA TOOLS**, that should solve your problem.

Comment: What about android studio?

Comment: It is already updated to Android studio, you should try and not worry.

Comment: I have a ongoing project, how do I add Pocketsphinx to it? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: @Sornii, just follow the instructions from tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thank you, I got it working now, I did little adjustments into gradle to work right. Now I have another problem that is: I put some words in a grammar file but it's recognizing words that are not in the grammar as a word in the grammar. `public <cars> = march | livina | grand livina | sentra | frontier | versa | altima;` <- this is the grammar.

Comment: Okay, I got it. When I set pocketsphinx to use a grammar file, it will get one of the words, even if the word is not in the list, it will pick the most accurate word, It's not like I wanted to. The continuous method is the one I do want, thanks.